# How to Generate a Constant Flow of Messages in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am creating a StreamInsight project designed to consume messages from another .NET application on a remote machine.

I’ve got a strong proof of concept CEP project finished that consumes the Twitter sample feed at http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json, parses it nicely and just generally works.

It access the message feed using code like this

```
Dim response = request.GetResponse()

Using streamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
```

My problem is that I’m not sure what technologies to use to create the .NET application on another machine that can send the message over an HTTP connection. I've worked with WCF WebServices before but they always return a single answer to a single request, not multiple responses to one request.

Can anyone give me a push toward a MS technology I can use to generate those messages?

Comment: WCF over MSMQ. Very easy to work with but not sure it will cross over networks (internet) easily.

Comment: I don't have the rep to comment so I have to post. Have you looked into chunking (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP request response works on the principle one request = one response.

Chunking is HTTP technique which allows sending HTTP response in multiple chunks but it is still single response with all its limitations. WCF chunking channel is not implementation of HTTP chunking. It is chunking of SOAP messages which requires the same chunking channel on both ends.

If you want to use multi responses over HTTP you must expose separate service on the client and server will call this service to provide multiple resonses with some correlation id to original request.

HTTP is not a protocol for continuous data flow. If you want continuous data flow use sockets directly with TCP.